# Hbase import/export change number of rows

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am using Hbase export using command.

```
  hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export "Table1" "hdfs path"
```

Then I use import command from HDFS to Hbase Table;

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import "hdfs path" "Table2"
```

Then I count number of row in both tables, I found mismatch number of rows

Table1:8301
Table2:8032

Please define what goes wrong with my system.

Comment: Are your both tables have same structure. Can you share details of both.

Comment: yes same structure. Issue with export. I see less number of record show in map-reduce report.